# Stored HL7 in a file and facing error while parsing line by line using python

Tags: python, hl7

I have stored my HL7 version 2.6 content in example.txt.I have no issue in reading the file but while parsing the file, the 1st line gets parsed but tells me that 2nd line is not hL7 when using hl7.ishl7(line) so it does not get parsed so it stops executing after the 2nd line. I don't know what is the issue in the content.

The content of the text file is:

```
MSH|^~\&|AcmeMed|Lab|Main HIS|St. Micheals|20130408031655||ADT^A01|6306E85542000679F11EEA93EE38C18813E1C635CB09673815639B8AD55D6775|P|2.6|
EVN||20050622101634||||20110505110517|
PID|||231331||Garland^Tracy||19010201|F||EU|147 Yonge St.^^LA^CA^58818|||||||28-457-773|291-697-644|
NK1|1|Smith^Sabrina|Second Cousin|
NK1|2|Fitzgerald^Sabrina|Second Cousin|
NK1|3|WHITE^Tracy|Second Cousin|
PV1||||||||^Fitzgerald^John^F|||||||||||5778985|||||||||||||||||||||||||20020606051116|
OBX|||WT^WEIGHT||78|pounds|
OBX|||HT^HEIGHT||57|cm|
```

For the code:

```
import json
import hl7
import re
i=0
with open('example.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
    print hl7.isfile(line)
    print line
    h=hl7.parse(line)
    i = i+1
    print i
```

Answer (score 2):

You should parse the whole *message*, not line by line. HL7 message lines by themselves are not valid HL7 messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go

```
result = hl7.parse(f)
```

Then access the desired segment - first value being line, next being segment.

```
name = result[2][4]
```

It's well detailed [here](http://python-hl7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#install)

Edit: And watch for the line break character, some people break it with \r and some with \n and this can be a little deadly.